# What are US libertarians' views on abortion according to polls/surveys?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, libertarianism

Someone challenged me in a comment on one of my posts as to what the breakdown of libertarians' views on abortion was (the context was USA).

While there are subjective guesses (the comment theorized 50/50 pro/con); I'm uncomfortable making such an assumption without data to back it up.

So, **what are US libertarians' views on abortion according to polls/surveys? Do the majority fall in pro-life or minority?**

I'm comfortable with any reasonably consistent definition of "libertarians", either small-l political orientation or large-L party, though the former (views/orientation) seems like a more interesting set to research while being harder to define well.

My preference is fore more thought-out and nuanced polls/surveys, e.g. ones allowing shades of gray on the views as opposed to only binary bumper-sticker choice.

Comment: I expect them to agree that it should not be paid with taxes.

Comment: It will be interesting to see what results are there, since there are your old school Libertarians, and then there are the modern uber-conservatives who call themselves Libertarians, mostly because they don't like to pay taxes, but are just fine with government meddling in all kinds of personal affairs, as long as it aligns with their own personal views.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Most libertarians do support having a police force and they don't consider it "meddling in ... personal affairs" when the police force prevents murder. Is abortion murder? That's a question that depends on your view of an unborn child, not on your view of the government's role in personal affairs.

Comment: @Readin - most people don't consider abortion to be murder, and there are no biblical, medical, scientific or legal foundations for such a redefinition. I love how you pretend that this doesn't somehow impact a fully grown adult human's body.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - in US, your comment is 100% factually wrong. Big surprise. Majority DO consider it murder, [backed by polls](http://www.gallup.com/poll/9904/public-opinion-about-abortion-indepth-review.aspx):
"*Q: Do you agree or disagree with this statement? Abortion is murder.* A: (Los Angeles Times, June 2000 poll:) : **57% agree; 36% disagree**"

Comment: @user4012 - when they list at least four different polls asking versions of that question, and you choose the only one where a majority says that it is murder, I'd say you perhaps don't understand what the term "100% factually" means.  You don't have anything within the last decade and a half to refer to?

Answer (score 6):

A survey by PRRI* found that 57% of libertarians oppose making it more difficult for a woman to get an abortion. For this survey, they categorized people as libertarian depending on their responses to some early questions. The details of this are on page 32 of the [full report](https://www.prri.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/2013.AVS_WEB-1.pdf).

The text from their executive summary is:

> Nearly 6-in-10 (57%, +/- 2.5%) libertarians oppose making it more difficult for a woman to get an abortion, a proportion identical to the general population. By contrast, strong majorities of Republicans overall (58%), Americans affiliated with the Tea Party (58%), and white evangelical Protestants (68%) favor making it more difficult for a woman to get an abortion. ([Source](https://www.prri.org/research/2013-american-values-survey/))

The [full report](https://www.prri.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/2013.AVS_WEB-1.pdf) is available on their website and it includes a methodology appendix. So is the [survey instrument](https://www.prri.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/AVS-Topline-FINAL.pdf) itself. The text of the question is:

> We    would    like    to    get    your    views    on    some    issues    that    are    being    discussed    in
> the    country    today.    Do    you    favor    or    oppose    the    following
> ...
> ?
>
> e. Making it more difficult for a woman to get an abortion
>
> Strongly favor
>
> Favor
>
> Oppose
>
> Strongly Oppose
>
> Refused

---

*I'm not familiar with PRRI. As with anything on the internet, interpret it with the usual skepticism.*

Comment: "making it more difficult" sounds like it requires government inference; How else can one make it more difficult? I'm surprised that only 57% of libertarians oppose that.

Comment: That is not at all implied by the question.  A person may read that into the question, but that isn't due to the survey.

Comment: It might be that 57% of the libetarians read that into the question. As I said: how to make it more difficult other than by government interference? I haven't seen an answer to that question yet.

Comment: @Sjoerd Libertarians don't oppose all government action. For example, all but the most extreme libertarians support having a police force whose job includes protecting people from murder, and even protecting children from being murdered by their parents. Whether this includes protecting unborn children from abortion doesn't depend on whether you are libertarian, but whether you consider the unborn child a person.